# Add options menu to QR reader application in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, menu

I'm learning to code apps for android and I'm trying to code an app that reads QR codes, but I want to add an options menu. I have a small code that does it, but when I try to add it the QR reader app the menu does not show. Can you tell me what is wrong with what I have so far?

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.view.View;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.zxing.Result;
import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
    private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    // Here I added the menu to the qr app
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.item1:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Item 1 Selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;

            case R.id.item2:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Item 2 Selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;

            case R.id.item3:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Item 3 Selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
//Here ends the part of the menu

    public void onClick(View v){
        mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        setContentView(mScannerView);
        mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
        mScannerView.startCamera();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mScannerView.stopCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result result) {
        Log.w("handleResult", result.getText());
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Scan result");
        builder.setMessage(result.getText());
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

    }
}
```

**Menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item  android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:title="Item 1"/>
    <item  android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:title="Item 2"/>
    <item  android:id="@+id/item3"
        android:title="Item 3"/>
</menu>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="114dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="Scan QR" />
    </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I know that the options menu works by itself, because I tested alone as a different app, and also the qr reader works by itself, but if I try to combine them the menu is not there. I'm a newbie on coding android apps, so I will appreciate your guidance. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your menu name you supplied is menu.xml but instead you are giving `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);`

you should replace

`getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);`

with

`getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);`

Comment: Yes I had a typo there, I changed it, but the result is the same. The app looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/WVbn1nB.png

Comment: did you set the theme?